# Выделять ли запятой слово "скорее" в предложении "Скорее дело в наличии природных ресурсов в стране"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Сложно говорить о какой-то последовательной экономической стратегии властей Азербайджана. Скорее дело в наличии природных ресурсов в стране.

Нужно ли выделять запятой "скорее" в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном примере ***скорее*** является наречием и не обособляется.

**Пояснение**

Сравним  предложения:

(1) **Скорее** дело в наличии природных ресурсов в стране.

(2) **Скорее всего**, дело в наличии природных ресурсов в стране.

(3) **Скорее говоря**, дело в наличии природных ресурсов в стране.

В заданном примере они могут использоваться на равных основаниях, но ***скорее всего*** и ***скорее говоря***  –  вводные слова (кроме редких исключений), они обособляются.

Вывод: **Поэтому обычно не стоит задумываться о сопоставлении** (оно практически всегда присутствует),  лучше считать ***скорее*** наречием, а ***скорее всего/скорее говоря*** – вводными словами.

**Но всё-таки встречаются примеры**, в которых **скорее** обособляется:

А я, **скорее**, даже – пострадавший. Разговорная стихотворная речь, инверсия (даже скорее)

Я не ищу состраданья, **скорее**, не должен искать.  Значение "скорее говоря."

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ справочной службы русского языка:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295555)

> Слово «скорее» не требует постановки знаков препинания, если в предложении подразумевается сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели»: они больше боятся, нежели что-то иное.

Вне широкого контекста не могу сказать уверенно, но вероятнее всего, у вас  подразумевается сопоставление, то есть предложение можно перестроить, не меняя смысла:
*Дело скорее в наличии природных ресурсов в стране, чем в какой-то последовательной экономической стратегии.*
В таком случае **запятая не нужна.**

> [Вопрос № 200506](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=200506)
>   Всегда ли слово "скорее" надо обособлять? Можно ли считать возможность замены на "скорее всего" однозначным признаком вводности, а следовательно, обособления? Есть ли еще какие-либо признаки или приемы? Правильна ли постановка запятой в данном примере: "Однако это, скорее, общие тенденции, чем жесткие правила"?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   В словарях в качестве синонимов вводному слову *скорее* даются слова *вернее, точнее*. В данном примере замена на *вернее* невозможна, корректно: *Однако это скорее общие тенденции, чем жесткие правила*.